# mac terminal ffmpeg batch recursive conversion preserving directory structure

Tags: macos, ffmpeg, terminal

i'm using ffmpeg on mac to batch convert .flv to .mp4 files. i'm trying to find all files in subdirectories of the current directory and save new files in the same directory.

for instance starting with:

```
subdirectory1/video1.flv
subdirectory1/video2.flv
subdirectory2/video1.flv
```

and ending with

```
subdirectory1/video1.mp4
subdirectory1/video2.mp4
subdirectory2/video1.mp4
```

i've gotten this far but can't figure out how to save with preserved recursive directories

```
for i in  `find -name . "*.flv"`; do ffmpeg -i "$i" "${i%.*}.mp4"; done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe there was a better way but this ultimately worked for my purposes. i had to rename the files and directories to remove spaces and rework the find command. the xargs inclusion tried to account for spaces but it didnt work

so i removed spaces from directories with this:

```
for f in *; do mv "$f" `echo $f | tr ' ' '_'`; done
```

and removed spaces from filenames with this

```
find . -type f -name "* *.flv" -exec bash -c 'mv "$0" "${0// /_}"' {} \;
```

then this command recursively reencoded my flv files and saved in their directory

```
for i in `find . -name "*.flv" -print0| xargs -0`; do ffmpeg -i "$i" -c:v libx264 -f mp4 "${i%.*}.mp4"; done
```

Comment: for good measure, this also takes a screen shot midway { 
for i in `find . -name "*.flv" -print0| xargs -0`; do ffmpeg -i "$i" -vcodec mjpeg -vframes 1 -an -f rawvideo -ss `ffmpeg -i "$i" 2>&1 | grep Duration | awk '{print $2}' | tr -d , | awk -F ':' '{print ($3+$2*60+$1*3600)/2}'` "${i%.*}.jpg"; done }